# getimagesize on application/octet-stream upload?

Tags: php

I am using mithril.js drag n drop, using FormData, it sends it successfully to back end but am unable to use getimagesize() on it. Why I need getimagesize is because of the library I'm using.

```
//var_dump on $_FILES
array (size=1)
    'upload' => 
        array (size=5)
            'name' => string '95ab94cadab44e81cfe6d3c83642680d.jpg' (length=36)
            'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
            'tmp_name' => string '/tmp/phpTj3iX3' (length=14)
            'error' => int 0
            'size' => int 743265
```

and heres the var_dump on getimagesize($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);

```
 boolean false
```

I've also tried this thinking it was just uploading the string:

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
//the error imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format
```

also tried just var_dumping the tmp file back out

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
var_dump($data);
//�����JFIF��������8Photoshop 3.0 ...
```

EDIT: the size of the file is 392kb but PHP says its 743kb and I am unsure why

Answer (score 0):

```
$binary_data = file_get_contents($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
$uri = 'data://application/octet-stream;base64,'  . base64_encode($binary_data);
$arr =  getimagesize($uri);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply however I var_dumped $arr and still get boolean false.